# Line series graphs gives error on resizing - highcharts

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I have used highcharts [single line series graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3iFU.png). It seems to work all fine but when I resize the page (just to check responsiveness or just it on mobile). The values disappear. I can see error in console logs.

[image]

That's how I generate the chart

```
Highcharts.stockChart('nav-chart', {

 tooltip: {
        pointFormat:"{point.y:.3f}\u20ac"
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    zoomType: 'x',
    pinchType: 'x',
    panning: false,
    <?php if (is_front_page()){ ?>
    height: 700,
    <?php } else { ?> 
    height: 500, 
    events: {
      load: updateLegendLabel 
    }    
    <?php } ?> 
  },
```

`updateLegendLabel` has some computation that generates the labels.

```
 var chrt = !this.chart ? this : this.chart;
  chrt.update({
    legend: {
      useHTML: true,
      symbolPadding: 0,
      symbolWidth: 0,
      symbolHeight: 0,
      symbolRadius: 0,    
      labelFormatter: function() {


        var lastVal = this.yData[this.yData.length - 1],
          chart = this.chart,
          xAxis = this.xAxis,
          points = this.points,
          avg = 0,
          counter = 0,
          min, max;
... there is some business logic down there
```

`points` var becomes null when I resize the page. Why is that so? Do I need to reupdate dataset or what?

Comment: your dataset should be in some global javascript variable so that it should be available on redraw as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting Server and Client side logic is not good. Better is to seperate logic using like this. Bellow one is just for idea not a exact code. But can be fixed if you provide complete code separating your server logic from client side logic.

```
<script>
//before graph area started
var dataA = '<?php echo $dataA;?>';
var dataB = '<?php echo $dataB;?>';
//graph logic started
// your graph code which can use above variables
// but the variable need to be available can be evaluated from your draw script.

</script>
```

then use these variables in your graph script.
Because on resizing of browser, graph is redrawing and its looking data is not available when graph is redrawing. But if above logic will be used then data will be available on every redraw

Comment: is there any way I can disable redrawing since on resizing is needed not the redrawing

Comment: i will not suggest you to disable redraw because redraw is required on every window size change event otherwise it will look very strange. better is to assign your php values above the script in some variables and then use those variables. Because doing this those variable data will be available all the time. Also server side code must always be separate and has many advantages.